# Java Min Max Method

Tags: java

Ive got an issue with my mutable methods on Java, the data structure is coming up with an error saying min and max cannot be resolved to a variable.

```
@Override
public Optional <T> min(){
    if (Set.isEmpty())
        return Optional.empty();

    else(
            T min = Collections.min(Set);
            return Optional.of(min);
}

@Override
public Optional <T> max() {
    if(Set.isEmpty())
        return Optional.empty();
    else (
            T max = Collections.max(Set);
            return Optional.of(max());
}
```

Comment: This code does not compile. Why is there an open parenthesis next to `else`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most importantly, you need curly braces around your `else` parts, for example:

```
    else {
        T min = Collections.min(Set);
        return Optional.of(min);
    }
```

This should compile.

There are a couple of minor issues:

I suggest you use braces around your `if` parts too.

I take `Set` to be an instance variable. If you want anyone else to be able to read your Java code (like people you want to ask quesions on Stack Overflow), do not use a variable name that begins with a capital letter. And especially do not use the name of a well known interface (`java.util.Set`) as a variable name. It will cause loads of confusion.

In the `max` method you got a pair of round parentheses too much after `max` in the creation of the `Optional`.